# PHP Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean? Por qué? (leer antes de votar negativo)

Tags: php, mysql

Cómo andan? Hace tiempo no aparezco por acá. Tengo estas tablas para presupuestos.
Cada presupuesto tiene una fecha de caducidad y uno (1) o mas estados (pendiente, enviado, etc.) y con este código en PHP
lo que intento es cambiar el estado del presupuesto a Caducado (6) para los que cumplan las condiciones.

Las tablas:

```
mysql> select id, fecha, validez from presupuestos where id < 4;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | fecha               | validez             |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2022-08-30 11:56:47 | 2022-09-01 11:56:47 |
|  2 | 2022-06-12 13:45:12 | 2022-06-15 13:45:12 |
|  3 | 2022-12-15 07:32:14 | 2022-12-18 07:32:14 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+

mysql> select * from presupuestos_estado where idPresupuesto < 4;
+----+---------------+----------+---------------------+----------------------------+
| id | idPresupuesto | idEstado | fecha               | observaciones              |
+----+---------------+----------+---------------------+----------------------------+
| 36 |             1 |        1 | 2022-06-12 13:45:12 |                            |
| 37 |             2 |        1 | 2022-06-12 13:45:12 |                            |
| 38 |             3 |        1 | 2022-12-15 07:32:14 |                            |
| 39 |             3 |        2 | 2022-12-26 22:49:06 |                            |
| 52 |             3 |        6 | 2022-12-27 14:08:54 | actualización automática   |
+----+---------------+----------+---------------------+----------------------------+
```

El código PHP:

```
/** manejador del resultset auxiliar */
$resultset2 = null;
$query = "select id
    from presupuestos
    where timediff(validez, now()) < 0";
$resultado = $mysql->consulta($query);
if (!$resultado) {
    $hay_errores = true;
} else {
    if ($mysql->num_rows > 0) {

                                                                 /***********************/
        while ($resultset = $mysql->resultado->fetch_assoc()) { /* esta línea da error */
                                                                /***********************/


            $query = "select pe.idEstado
                from presupuestos_estado pe
                where (pe.idPresupuesto = " . $resultset['id'] . ")
                order by pe.fecha desc
                limit 1";
            $resultado = $mysql_aux->consulta($query);
            if (!$resultado) {
                $hay_errores = true;
                $errores[]['aviso'] = "El presupuesto Nro. " . $resultset['id'] . " no se pudo actualizar (error $resultado)";
            } else {
                if ($mysql_aux->num_rows > 0) {
                    $ppto_aux = new Presupuesto();
                    while ($resultset2 = $mysql_aux->resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                        if ($resultset2['idEstado'] <= 3) {
                            $resultado = $ppto_aux->actualizar_estado((int)$resultset['id'], 6, "actualización automática");
                        }
                        if (($resultado !== true) and ($resultado != -6)) {
                            $hay_errores = true;
                            $errores[]['aviso'] = "El presupuesto Nro. " . $resultset['id'] . " no se pudo actualizar (error $resultado)";
                        } else {
                            else $errores[]['exito'] = "se actualizó el presupuesto Nro. " . $resultset['id'];
                        }
                    }
                    unset($ppto_aux);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ($hay_errores) {
        $errores[]['error'] = "No se pudieron actualizar los presupuestos caducados";
        $errores[]['aviso'] = "Es posible que los resultados no estén actualizados. Verificar la información individualmente";
    } else {
        $errores[]['informacion'] = "La actualización se ejecutó correctamente";
    }
}
```

El problema lo tengo en que cuando hay que actualizar el estado de algún presupuesto, PHP me tira este error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean
```

Sin embargo, ANTES de refrescar la pagina, si miro en la base de datos, la actualización se llevó a cabo correctamente.
Si no hay que actualizar nada, no muestra ningún error. No entiendo por qué.

Desde ya. gracias.

PD: ya sé que todo este código se podría optimizar mejorando (unificando) las consultas y estuve leyendo y probando sin obtener
resultados consistentes. Todo esto si que me los da.

PD2: el objeto `$mysql` funciona correctamente: lo uso en el resto de la aplicación.

Comment: @Excorpion Imagino que te referis al método (en la línea del error), no? Es es el `var_dump($mysql->resultado)` justo antes de la línea del error y con actualizaciones por hacer: `object(mysqli_result)#13 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(3) ["type"]=> int(0) } `. Me da 3 líneas, que es correcto.

Comment: Y si te referís al `var_dump($resultado)` (el de la consulta), es este: `bool(true) `. Lo que también es correcto: la consulta se ejecutó correctamente. El otro `var_dump` muestra tres resultados.... todo parece correcto

Comment: @Excorpion Es que `$resultado` solo contiene `bool(true)` si no hubo error en la consulta, o `bool(false)` si hubo error. Los resultados de la consulta los manejo con `$mysql->resultado` y antes verifico con `$mysql->num_rows`. Ya te digo, el objeto `$mysql` funciona correctamente, por eso no entiendo a qué se debe. Tendrá algo que ver la segunda conexión (`$mysql_aux`) para no perder el primer `$resultset`?

Comment: @Excorpion Claro, `$resultado` la vuelvo a utilizar mas adelante. Ahí no está el problema, repito.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es incorrecto:

```
/***********************/
    while ($resultset = $mysql->resultado->fetch_assoc()) { 
/* esta línea da error */
```

Para leer a `$resultado` no debes pasar por el objeto `$mysql`, porque `$resultado` es un objeto en sí mismo.

No veo lo que haces en `consulta()`, pero imagino que desde ahí devuelves un recurso, fruto de la ejecución de `query()` o de `execute()`. [Si revisas los ejemplos de código del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) verás que el resultado de una consulta es un recurso en sí mismo, y debes leerlo directamente, no pasar por el objeto de la conexión para ello.

Así debería funcionar, salvo otros errores:

```
while ($resultset = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { 
    //Usar $resultset
}
```

Tu código necesita todavía muchas mejoras y ser optimizado en varios niveles, pero poco a poco lo lograrás.

Comment: Como dije en los comentarios del post original, `$resultado` y `$mysql->resultado` son dos cosas distintas. El primero contiene un valor booleano que indica si se ejecutó correctamente la consulta o no. El segundo, en caso de una consulta exitosa y con resultados, contiene dichos resultados. Esto funciona bien: `$ids_pptos = array();
  while ($resultset = $mysql->resultado->fetch_assoc()) { $ids_pptos[] = $resultset['id']; }
  foreach($ids_pptos as $indice => $id_ppto) {`

Comment: @julio pero ¿`$mysql` no es tu conexión a la BD? ¿Has probado como te indico en la respuesta? ¿Podrías mostrar lo que tienes en tu método `consulta()`?

Comment: `$mysql` es la clase desde donde gestiono la conexión, las consultas, el nro de resultados, los errores...  `$mysql->consulta()` devuelve SIEMPRE `true` o `false`. Al resultset se accede desde `$mysql->resultado`. Si lees los comentarios del post original, hice dos `var_dump()`: `$resultado` y `$mysql->resultado` y los resultados son correctos. Y a pesar del error de PHP, la actualización se ejecuta correctamente.

Comment: @julio estás queriendo reinventar la rueda. `mysqli` es completa, tiene todos los métodos y clases relacionadas para controlar cada cosa, no tienes que reinventar. Sospecho que el error se debe a querer usar `fetch_assoc` sobre un resultado de una consulta `UPDATE`, lo cual no es posible porque ese tipo de consultas no arrojan un conjunto de resultados, sino la cantidad de filas afectadas.

Comment: Mas allá de la reinvención de la rueda, que no es el caso ahora, esa línea solo procesa un `select`. Y lo procesa siempre y cuando haya resultados. De todas maneras tomo nota para revisar mi clase `$mysql` (es una clase que viene de hace mucho y la he ido adaptando para no tener que actualizar otros tantos códigos que tengo por ahí). De todas maneras, he conseguido unificar las consultas y he realizado una revisión y reescritura del código. Dejo la pregunta no para que voten negativo, sino para que quien quiera lea y analice y trate de comprender y explicar por qué da ese error. Gracias!